# How can i design better a Inventory, Order sync web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, architecture, saas, subscriptions, offlineapps

I have a web application that displays inventory, orders, tracking information from drop-shippers for orders and tracking updates. When a customer logs in, he will see all the above information in different pages.

I have a Console based application in the server that hosts 4 background workers to do each of the above tasks and updates the database. Now i have one console application for each customer. I did this because for any reason the console application fails because of one customer's data, it should not effect others.

Is there a better approach or any existing tools, api, frameworks available to support this kind of stack in Microsoft? Or what i am doing is correct and best approach? Are there any technologies that are more stable to support Subscription based membership, Offline data sync, Queue User requests and notifying user when they are completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at the Azure Queues and Webjobs (Links below)

With a queue structure, you can simply decouple your application and make the application only do what is needed. Your main application can then just put relevant and needed information in the Queue and forget about it.

Next (and perhaps the most crucial part of this) you can write a simple console application that will run when a queue is present and ready. The beauty of this is that you not only can have multiple webjobs doing the same thing (I don't recommend it) but also, you only need to have and maintain one Console application. If the application crashes, it will simply restart it again (within a few seconds) and go back at it again.

Below, please find a link to the tutorial of how to make a sample Queue and Webjob:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/?rnd=1